# perl regex to capture into variable only an exact match within a string

Tags: regex, perl

i need help with this regex to capture only the exact match within a string and put it in a variable

i only want to extrapolate these values (fixed list; no other numbers):

```
004010H222A1 or 
004010H223A2 or 
004010H220A1 or 
004010H279A1 or 
004010H279A1 or 
004010H217
```

from the string given

example:

```
$str = "this is the code 004010H222A1 the rest is irrelevant";
$str = "the random number is 004010H223A2 ** anything else is irrelevant";
$str = "the last lottery number 004010H220A1 ~~ the rest is irrelevant";
$str = "yet another random sentence 004010H279A1 the rest is irrelevant";
$str = "any sentence before what i want 004010H279A1 the rest is irrelevant";
$str = "last winning number 004010H217~~~";


if ($str =~ /\b(004010H[2][1|2|7][0|2|3|7|9])(A[1|2])?\b/){
print "found exact match\n";
##put result into a variable
##example:
## $exact_match = <found eg 004010H222A1>; 
##print $exact_match;
}
```

how can i capture the exact match of what i want into a variable then display it? maybe i just can't see the forest for the trees. thank you in advance for your help

Comment: ^.*(004010H[0-9A]{0,10})

Comment: Or this for just that set:  ^.*(004010H222A1|004010H223A2|004010H220A1|004010H279A1|004010H279A1|004010H217)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a given list of patterns

```
my @fixed = qw(004010H222A1 004010H223A2 004010H220A1 
    004010H279A1 004010H279A1 004010H217);

my $str = "this is the code 004010H222A1 the rest is irrelevant";

my @found = grep { $str =~ /$_/ } @fixed;
```

what matches all such patterns in the string. Note that you may need word boundaries (`/\b$_\b/`), albeit not if the patterns are so distinct in the surrounding text as shown. If the pattern itself contains any non-word characters then you'd need to build the sub-pattern for the "boundary."

If you are certain there is only one of them in the string or need only the first one

```
my ($found) = grep { $str =~ /$_/ } @fixed;
```

or by constructing the pattern with alternation first

```
my $re = join '|', map { quotemeta } @fixed;

my $found = $str =~ /$re/;  # consider using word-boudaries /\b$re\b/
```

This may be more efficient since it starts the regex engine only once, but on the other hand with only a few (or a single one?) options we do engage in all that overhead to form the alternation.

Depending on details you may want to sort by `length`first, either by longest or shortest

```
my $re = join '|', map { quotemeta } sort { length $a <=> lenght $b } @fixed;
...
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55734041/4653379) for discussion of reasoning behind these options.

---

If you have more possibilities, with the exact pattern shown in the question, the pattern is: digits followed by letters-or-digits, terminated by non-letter-digits.

```
my $pattern = qr/([0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9]/;

my ($found) = $str =~ /$pattern/;
```

The above matches if the pattern is immediately preceded by a non-digit character (like `~`), not only space. It also allows low-case letters, drop `a-z` if they cannot be there. You can further restrict this if it is certain that it has leading zeros.

Comment: that's it! thnx much. been playing around and i like your idea. thnx again

Comment: @user2585000 Welcome, glad you like it :) It is a nice little 'technique' when you have a list of fixed patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Just to put my two cents in:

```
\b004010H2[127][02379](?:A[12])?\b
# \b - match a word boundary
# match 004010H2 literally
# [127] one of 1,2 or 7
# followed by one of 0,2,3,7 or 9
# (?:....)? is a non capturing group and optional in this case
```

*Hint:* Obviously, this is able to match your numbers but other combinations like `004010H210A2` as well. It totally depends on your input strings. If you only have these six alternatives, you're probably on the safer side with simple string functions.
See <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aM6dM5/1)</kbd>.

Comment: thnx, that demo website helped to debug a few ideas presented. thnx also for pointing out the optional part capturing group